# find all child control in panel javascript

Tags: javascript

I am struck in javascript all day can figure out the fast way to get the control in the panel.

I can use this one to get all a tab in the page. However the page will have over 100 a. I know the panel in the page. My question is how I get the a tag in the panel control.  Hope someone can tell me. Thanks in advance.

```
var myform = Form1.elements
var aTags = myform.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Comment: Please post your HTML, an a demo to reproduce the issue, your question as-is isn't very helpful.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('[name=form1] a')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myform = Form1.elements  <-- elements is wrong
var aTags = myform.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

It should just be the form

```
var anchors = document.getElementById("yourFormId").getElementsByTagName('a');
```

or

```
var anchors = document.Form1.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

[elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.elements) returns a collection and only the form elements.

Comment: Yes. `document.formName.getElementsByTagName('a')` would get all the anchors too.